# SQL Server 2008 - Partitioning and Clustered Indexes

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

So let me preface by saying I do not have total control over my db design, so a lot of the aspects of the current system **cannot be changed** for the purposes of this scenario.

Comments about how we should rethink aspects of the design are likely correct but unhelpful :)

I have a very large table, approx 150 fields wide and about 600m rows,  that drives a large number of processes.  This is in a data warehouse situation so we don't have ANY updates/inserts outside the scheduled load process, so it is heavily indexed.

A decision has been made to try partitioning this table, and I have some concerns about indexing a partitioned table.  I don't have any experience with partitioning, so any input or links are appreciated.  I couldn't locate specifically what I am after on BOL or msdn.

Currently we cluster on a field that we'll call `IncidentKey` which is a `varchar(50)` and not unique - we could have between 1-100 records with the same `IK` (no comments please).  We do often get new data on old `IncidentKey` records so it's not sequential either.

I understand I need to include my partition field, `IncidentDate`, in my clustered index key for the partition to work correctly.  I'm thinking it would be `IncidentKey, IncidentDate`.

The question is, how will the mechanics of a clustered index work on a 2 part key in a partitioned table, if a record in a "new" partition should be before a record in an "old" partition in the clustered index?

For example, I have 5 records:

```
IncidentKey    Date

ABC123        1/1/2010
ABC123        7/1/2010
ABC123        1/1/2011
XYZ999        1/1/2010
XYZ999        7/1/2010
```

If I get a new record for `ABC123, 2/1/2011` it will need to be in the clustered index **BEFORE** `XYZ999, 1/1/2010`.  How does this work?

I'm assuming fragmentation and pointers, but I can't find any info on the physical storage and configuration of non-partitioned clustered indexes on partitioned  tables with dual-part keys.

Comment: Why was the decision to partition the table made? What are the expected benefits from partitioning?

Comment: @Remus - I'm actually doing it as a test, so we will have one partitioned and one non-partitioned version.  The expected benefit is decreased load times, and index build times.  We do monthly ETL operations that take about a week and the hope is this will reduce that time significantly.  We also have deployment of around 3 TB that we hope to reduce with this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A partitioned table is really more like a collection of individual tables stitched together. So your in example of clustering by `IncidentKey` and partition by `IncidentDate`, say that the partitioning function splits the tables into two partitions so that 1/1/2010 is in partition 1 and 7/1/2010 is partition two. The data will be layed out on disk as:

```
Partition 1:
IncidentKey    Date
ABC123        1/1/2010
ABC123        1/1/2011
XYZ999        1/1/2010

Partition 2:
IncidentKey    Date
ABC123        7/1/2010
XYZ999        7/1/2010
```

At a low level there really are two, distinct rowsets. Is the query processor that gives the illusion of a single table by creating plans that seek, scan and update *all* rowsets together, as one.

Any row in any non-clustered index will have have the clustered index key to which it corresponds, say `ABC123,7/1/2010`. Since the clustered index key always contains the partitioning key column, the engine will always know in what partition (rowset) of the clustered index to search for this value (in this case, in partition 2).

Now whenever you're dealing with partitioning you must consider if your NC indexes will be aligned (NC index is partitioned exactly the same as the clustered index) or non-aligned (NC index is non-partitioned, or partitioned differently from clustered index). Non-aligned indexes are more flexible, but they have some drawbacks:

- non-aligned indexes [require large amounts of memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187526.aspx) for certain query plans
- non-aligned indexes prevent efficient partition switch operations

Using aligned indexes solves these issues, but brings its own set of problems, because this physical, storage design, option ripples into the data model:

- aligned indexes mean unique constrains can no longer be created/enforced (except for the partitioning column)
- all foreign keys referencing the partitioned table must include the partitioning key in the relation (since the partitioning key is, due to alignment, in *every* index), and this in turn requires that all tables referencing the partitioned table contain partitioning key column value. Think Orders->OrderDetails, if Orders have OrderID but is partitioned by OrderDate, then OrderDetails must contain not only OrderID, but *also* OrderDate, in order to properly declare the foreign key constraint.

These effects I found seldom called out at the beginning of a project that deploys partitioning, but they exists and have serious consequences.

If you think aligned indexes are a rare or extreme case, then consider this: in many cases the cornerstone of ETL and partitioning solutions is the fast switch in of staging tables. Switch in operations require aligned indexes.

Oh, one more thing: all my argument about foreign keys and the ripple effect of adding the partitioning column value to other tables applies equally to **joins**.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for.  We will need to use aligned indexes b/c the swapping is a part of the draw for what we want to do with this.  We also do a TON of aggregate functions grouping on that `IncidentKey` field, which I think this will seriously hamper.  I appreciate all the detail!

Comment: Usually the benefits of partition switch operations outweigh all the problems.

Comment: That's our hope, we will see soon!

Answer (score 9):

> When a clustered index has multiple
>   partitions, each partition has a
>   B-tree structure that contains the
>   data for that specific partition. For
>   example, if a clustered index has four
>   partitions, there are four B-tree
>   structures; one in each partition. 
>   Ref. [Clustered Index Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443.aspx)

[Special Guidelines for Partitioned Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187526.aspx)

You can rebuild specific partitions of a partitioned index.

e.g.

```
ALTER INDEX IX_TransactionHistory_TransactionDate
ON Production.TransactionHistory
REBUILD Partition = 5;
GO
```

Comment: +1 For the link, I had read the special guidelines but missed that paragraph.  Followup question - we do a lot of aggregation on the `IncidentKey` field, do you think this would adversely affect performance (I realize I will still need to do testing)?

Comment: I don't know all your specific circumstances but it strikes me you might be better off partitioning by IncidentDate?

Comment: We are partitioning on the date, but the clustered key is on `IncidentKey` - we do a ton of joins on this and it's kind of an institutional thing that we use that to cluster.  I'm testing an alternate key but for  now this is what I have to use.